# CC1310 RX mode detect

Tags: microcontroller

Is it possible to detect when the CC1310 is switched to receive (RX) mode at the very beginning?

I want to use an oscilloscope to observe something like a TTL signal.

I'm studying the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1310.pdf?ts=1676457188445&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCC1310) but can't find any information on this.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "very beginning" and "is switched to"? I don't think there are pins routed out from the M0 core, they are all handled by the M3. But don't you put the radio core into Rx mode from the M3 core? Why don't you set a pin at this point? Or do you want to check if the M0 "actually" is in Rx mode? The radio core also throws a couple of interrupts (section 23.3.2.3 in the reference manual), maybe one of them serves your purpose or comes with status information.

Comment: @Max, thanks for your answer. I found a place in the code where M3 sends the StartRX command to M0 . Before this line of code I set a Pin and now I watch on the oscilloscope when RX starts.